# How can I run a binary executable with input file (bash command) in Python?

Tags: python, bash, command, executable

I have a binary executable named as **"abc"** and I have a input file called as **"input.txt"**. I can run these with following bash command:

```
./abc < input.txt
```

How can I run this bash command in Python, I tried some ways but I got errors.

Edit:
I also need the store the output of the command.

Edit2:

I solved with this way, thanks for the helps.

**input_path** = path of the **input.txt** file.

```
out = subprocess.Popen(["./abc"],stdin=open(input_path),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout,stderr = out.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this with `subprocess` module?

Comment: Yes, I tried subprocess module but I could not run only this command. I can run another commands easily with subprocess but it could not work for this one.

Comment: The bash symbol `<` signifies input redirection. Take a look at the stdin argument for subprocess in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 1):

use os.system

```
import os
os.system("echo test from shell");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using subprocess is the best way to invoke system commands and executables. It provides better control than os.system() and is intended to replace it. The python documentation link below provides additional information.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Here is a bit of code that uses subprocess to read output from head to return the first 100 rows from a txt file and process it row by row. It gives you the output (out) and any errors (err).

```
mycmd = 'head -100 myfile.txt'
(out, err) = subprocess.Popen(mycmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()                                  
myrows = str(out.decode("utf-8")).split("\n")                                                                           
for myrow in myrows: 
    # do something with myrow
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `os` module. The following code works perfectly fine.

```
import os

path = "path of the executable 'abc' and 'input.txt' file"
os.chdir(path)
os.system("./abc < input.txt")
```

Hope this works :)